# Can I trigger GitLab pipeline CI from a backend of my application or remotly

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, devops, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

For example when a user clicks on the button submit I want to trigger a pipeline CI/CD

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, gitlab provides official API

In your case you should POST into /projects/:id/pipeline

Example:

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/pipeline?ref=master"
```

Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#create-a-new-pipeline

Comment: With  official API and POST into /projects/:id/pipeline will return data for any pipeline not triggering a pipeline remotely

Answer (score 0):

it works by using :

```
curl -X POST \
     -F token=TOKEN \
     -F ref=REF_NAME \
     https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/25865536/trigger/pipeline
```